# How to Automate terminal commands of ROS using a python script

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, ros

I am currently trying to write an executable program in python that runs the following ROS command: `rostopic echo dvrk/PSM1/position_cartesian_current` however despite reading the ROS Tutorials, I am unsure how to go about doing this. Within a file called `arm.py` the following subscriber and definition already exist:

```
rospy.Subscriber(self.__full_ros_namespace + '/position_cartesian_current', PoseStamped, self.__position_cartesian_current_cb)

def __position_cartesian_current_cb(self, data):
        self.__position_cartesian_current = posemath.fromMsg(data.pose)
```

Am I supposed to reuse this subscriber and definition in the new automated python script? After obtaining the current Cartesian position, the robot will subsequently be moved to a different position, which can currently be accomplished using ROS commands in the terminal, however, the aim is to write a python script that automates these commands. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import rospy
from tf import transformations
from tf_conversions import posemath
from std_msgs.msg import String, Bool, Float32, Empty, Float64MultiArray
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, PoseStamped, Vector3, Quaternion, Wrench, WrenchStamped, TwistStamped

def callback(data):
  rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + data.data)

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber(self.__full_ros_namespace + '/position_cartesian_current', PoseStamped, callback)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a new script or will you reuse `arm.py`? Can you please provide the full `arm.py` code? If you can create a [mre] it would be perfect.

Comment: I am trying to create a new python script that implements the publishers/subscribers within the arm.py file - so currently if I type the command: rostopic echo dvrk/PSM1/position_cartesian_current into the terminal, the position and the orientation of the arm is displayed continuously. The idea is that by running this new python file, I should be able to initially get the current position of the arm, and using the ROS commands, move the arm to the desired location.

Comment: The arm.py file can be found via this link: https://github.com/nortega1/dvrk-ros/blob/44c8604b6c120e91f5357e7fd3649a8f7936c504/dvrk_python/src/dvrk/arm.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is write a Python ROS Node to subscribe to the topic and implement your logic.

You can do so by following [this guide](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29).

The main idea is to subscribe to the position topic, get the relevant data in the callback function and publish, in that same callback, the commands you usually perform by command line.

To reproduce a simple `rostopic echo`, you can just print the values you receive in the callback.

Comment: Is the additional code that I've added to the original post along the correct lines? Sorry, I'm still getting to grips with ROS

Comment: The code is the correct one for subscribing a topic and retrieving the data. Take a read at the guide, it is really well written.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Python automation script, it is a Python ROS program which can be executed as a ROS node (using rosrun). What you are accomplish by doing this is the same with publishing manual messages through ROS built-in terminal commands. This program will execute callback whenever a message is published at "/position_cartesian_current" topic.

If you do not want to execute bunch of commands at different terminals whenever you want to try something, ROS offers you the ability to create launch files (roslaunch) which reduces your execution pipeline to a single roslaunch command. This is heavily used in ROS community to automate processes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this doc](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html) `PoseStamped` message contained from `Pose` and `Header` messages, so to obtain to the `Pose` values try it:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped,

def callback(data):
  print(data.pose)

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber(self.__full_ros_namespace + '/position_cartesian_current', 
    PoseStamped, callback
)
    rospy.spin()
```